# javascript get element id from json

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a (simple, I guess) problem with quotes, single quotes, double quotes.
I have a JS that sends data to a php file, which responds sending some data back with json. In the code below, `row.Dispon` is part of the response (and is working OK). But I want to "echo" `row.Element` inside getElementById with no success. I've tried `"+row.Element+"`, or `"'+row.Element+'"`. What I'm doing wrong?

```
if (row.Dispon=="ImageReload") {
  var text='Image changed';   
  document.getElementById(+row.Element+).value="due";
}
```

Comment: Please add a sample of you row object as well. Also what kind of HTML element is the targeted one?

Comment: Doesn't `document.getElementById(row.Element)` work? You don't need quotes neither concatenation here.

Comment: What the hell!..  `document.getElementById(row.Element)` is the solution. I've been stuck for a couple of hours with such a nonsense! Thanks caCtus!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your code snippet only, this should do the job for that specific problem:

```
if (row.Dispon == "ImageReload") {
  var text = 'Image changed';   
  document.getElementById(row.Element).value = "due";
}
```

You would need quotes (or double quotes) and `+` operators if you were trying to build a `string`. See this example:

```
var id = 42;
document.getElementById('myId' + id).value = 'something';
```

Assuming that `row.Element` contains a `string` already, you can directly pass it to `getElementById()`.

Some advice here:

- [Read more about functions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)
- [Read more about `Document.getElementById` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [Consider using `Document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)